# Every cell complex is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Every cell complex is homotopy equivalent to a  CW complex.

A cell complex is more general than a CW complex in that the cells need not be attached in increasing order of dimension.

Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Maybe this would be of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23415/cw-structure-on-spaces-obtained-by-attaching-cells-wildly

Comment: It is also mentioned here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74863/what-does-actually-being-a-cw-complex-provide-in-algebraic-topology/74904#74904